# How to transcode audio of video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to transcode an audio of video. I have a live stream(video-h264, audio-mp2). I need to convert an audio to aac codec and stream it. I don't want to waste a lot of resource for video processing. How can I do it with ffmpeg? (I have already tried with copy option.)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use to convert mkv's so that they work on my Chromecast with AAC audio:

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -vcodec copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output-transcoded.mkv
```

Comment: You don't need `-strict experimental` to use the encoder `aac` unless your `ffmpeg` is outdated.

Comment: OK. Cheers. I will remove that part and see if it still works. I actually copied it from another post somewhere a while ago.